# Hive regex not working as expected

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table that has an alphanumeric string as a primary key. I want to select rows where the key starts with a particular set of characters, so I use

```
Select * from my table where pk like '[A-Z]%' limit 5;
```

For some reason this returns nothing, while the query below returns 5 rows:

```
Select * from my table where pk like 'F%' limit 5;
```

Specifically, there seems to be a problem with how Hive processes the regex brackets []. Another query that returns nothing is:

```
Select * from my table where pk like '[F]%' limit 5;
```

Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

PS: I also tried

```
Select * from my table where pk rlike 'F%' limit 5;
```

And it too, returned nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match a regex expression you should use the RLIKE operator with Java-like regex syntax.

```
Select * from my table where pk rlike '^[A-Z].*' limit 5;
```

[source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize Hive uses Java regex. You have an extra $ in your regex string - remove it and I'll mark you as the answer.

Comment: Yep sorry I actually meant '^[A-Z].*' : the '^' character matching the beginning of expression